# Remove white space inside single quotes before and after text inside the quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am using a third-party plugin for javascript called QueryBuilder.

The problem is there is no way to trim the input after saved so the data is being saved like

```
testName='   test   '
```

this is my javascript code, which is removing all spaces which is not what I want, I am trying to remove just space in the single quotes before and after all the text. Pretty much like a trim but the trim is not working so I need a regex to replace method

```
get_condition_sql__str = $.trim(get_condition_sql.sql);
                get_condition_sql__clean = get_condition_sql__str.replace(/\s/g, '')
                console.log(get_condition_sql__clean);
                jQuery('.exception_conditions__sql').val(get_condition_sql__clean);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lookahead for exactly one `'` before the end of the string:

```js
const input = `testName='   test   '`;
const cleaned = input.replace(/ +(?=[^']*'$)/g, '');
console.log(cleaned);
```

There's only one word in the input, but if you need to preserve spaces between words inside the quotes, alternate between matching a `'` on either side of spaces instead:

```js
const input = `testName='   test test2   '`;
const cleaned = input.replace(/' +| +'/g, "'");
console.log(cleaned);
```

Comment: The second one works well, preserves the space in the middle like I need it and removes from the end but only small issue is it leaves the space in the front. Still better just enough though, most complain was the space at the end anyways so thanks a lot!

Comment: Run the snippet - it looks to remove the space in front as desired.

Answer (score 1):

**Please use this one for left space remove:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 
var original_str3 = "   This is a string"
 
//Strips all space to the left of the string
alert( original_str3.trimLeft() + ' <--- Without any spaces on the left' );
 
</script>
```

**Or use this one for right space remove:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 
var original_str4 = "This is a string   "
 
//Strips all space to the right of the string
alert( original_str4.trimRight() + ' <--- Without any spaces on the right' );
```

**For Remove space from both side character or string:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 
var original_str2 = "S    t    r  in  g"
//Strips excessive white spaces i.e. retains only one space between each letter
var white_space_stripped_str = original_str2.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
 
alert(white_space_stripped_str + ' <---- With exactly one space between each letter in case each letter has multiple spaces');
 
</script>
```

If any other are required then please let me know.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to replace "blue" with "red" in the paragraph below:</p>

<p id="demo">"vSourceCountry = 'TEST'"</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var str = `testName='   test test2   '`; 
  var res = str .replace(/' +| +'/g, "'");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Result:

```
Click the button to replace "Microsoft" with "W3Schools" in the paragraph  below:

    testName='test test2'
```

Or You can use etc as per required:

```
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp
```

Comment: only problem is the string is actually stored like example = "vSourceCountry = 'TEST'" so trim doesnt trim inside the single quotes just the double

Comment: @MichaelDaSilva thanks please user this one :

!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to replace "blue" with "red" in the paragraph below:</p>

<p id="demo">"vSourceCountry = 'TEST'"</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
  var res = str.replace(/'/g, "");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>

Comment: @MichaelDaSilva thanks If its good  for us then please let me know If other changes are required https://forums.asp.net/t/1713910.aspx?How+to+remove+single+and+double+quotes+from+a+string+